# Sublime Text open a specific file with the command palette or key binding

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

How do I open a specific file with a custom command palette entry or with a key binding aka shortcut key?

There are some files I open a lot but are not associated with any specific project. It would be useful to be able to open them quickly using the command palette or with a key binding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It took a few minutes of trial and error to work out how but here's how to do it.

To add an entry in the command palette to open a specific file, add a modified version of the following template to your user `Default.sublime-commands` file.

```
// Modify the caption "File Open: Whatever" to something
// appropriate and of course change the file path.

{ "caption": "File Open: Whatever", "command": "open_file", 
  "args": {"file": "/path/to/whatever"} },
```

To add a key binding to open a specific file, add a modified version of the following template to your user `Default (OS).sublime-keymap` file.

```
// Modify the key bindings to what you want and change the file path.

{ "keys": ["ctrl+t", "ctrl+w"], "command": "open_file", 
  "args": {"file": "/path/to/whatever"} },
```

Hope this helps.